Problem with "showonlyrefs": vertical spacing is modified among slides originated from the same frame
I have a tex file
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\hypersetup{
  hypertexnames=false,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1ex plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\colorlet{ombra}{black}
\newcommand{\akiramath}[2][]{%
  \tcboxmath[
    enhanced,
    colback=fondo,
    frame empty,
    fuzzy shadow={0.5mm}{-0.5mm}{0.3mm}{1pt}{ombra},
    #1
]{\displaystyle #2}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\qtextq}[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Sketch proof of Theorem 1}
\framesubtitle{Convergence of marginal densities}

Let $\mu_t$ be the \textcolor{magenta}{sub-probability} measure induced by $\ell_t$. We need to prove
\begin{equation}
\akiramath{
\mu_t \in \sP_p (\bR^d)
\qtextq{and}
\lim_n W_p (\mu^n_t, \mu_t) = 0.
}
\end{equation}

\pause

The Fokker-Planck equation is
\begin{equation} \tag{m-FP1} \label<2-3>{mr:thm1:proof:eq3}
\partial_t \ell^n (t, x) = \begin{multlined}[t] -  \partial_{x_i} \{ b^i(t, x, (\mathcolor{magenta}{\rho^n * \ell_t^n}) (x), \mu^n_t) \ell^n (t, x) \} \\
+ \frac{1}{2} \partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j} \{ a^{i, j} (t, x, \mu^n_t) \ell^n (t, x) \} .
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\pause

Taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we get that $\ell$ satisfies
\begin{equation} \tag{FP1} \label<3>{mr:thm1:proof:eq4}
\partial_t \ell (t, x) = \begin{multlined}[t]
- \partial_{x_i} \{ b^i (t, x, \ell_t (x), \mu_t) \ell (t, x) \} \\
+ \frac{1}{2} \partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j} \{ a^{i, j} (t, x, \mu_t) \ell (t, x) \} .
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

I have one frame and two \pause, so there are three slides.

I expect that the vertical spacing between paragraphs remains the same for those slides originated from the same frame.
However, the vertical spacing is modified between slides 2 and 3. This makes the transition from slide 2 to slide 3 not smooth.
This unwanted modification disappears when I comment out \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}.

Could you elaborate on this issue and how to fix it?

Please minimise your examples before posting. Many of the packages don't seem relevant to the question.

The best way to use \pause is to not use it:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{visibleenv}<+->
\begin{equation}
1
\end{equation}
\end{visibleenv}
\begin{visibleenv}<+->
\begin{equation} \tag{m-FP1} \label<2-3>{mr:thm1:proof:eq3}
2
\end{equation}
\end{visibleenv}
\begin{visibleenv}<+->
\begin{equation}  \tag{FP1} \label<3>{mr:thm1:proof:eq4}
3
\end{equation}
\end{visibleenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



The way of using \pause is so simple and intuitive...
